# Spring data rest deleting using id in url is not calling deleteById method

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am implementing Spring Data Rest and my resource has the default delete endpoint of /table/{id} when called with the DELETE method. My repository interface extends `PagingAndSortingRepository` and `QuerydslPredicateExecutor` and thus has the following overriden methods for delete:

1. deleteById(@NonNull ID id);
2. delete(@NonNull T entity);
3. deleteAll(@NonNull Iterable entities);
4. deleteAll();

On calling the above mentioned endpoint I find that Spring is making a call to `findById` and then calling delete(entity) somehow passing `entity` as the result of `findById`. This is causing me trouble with security as this requires the user to have permission over `findById`, which is permitted to only certain roles, and `delete`, which is permitted by different roles.

What can I do to tell spring to use `deleteById` instead when a DELETE method call is made to the deafult endpoint with ID in the path?

Comment: How can a user delete an object which he cannot see? I think if somebody has DELETE permission to an object that should automatically give him GET permission too.

Comment: I am bound by business requirements.

Comment: You can implement DELETE in your own controller and which overrides the default DELETE provided by spring data rest.